# Manually inserted rows in a CollectionTable are not fetched by the service

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I would like to understand some behaviour which seems a bit strange to me in a Spring Boot application. I tested with `Spring Boot 2.4.5` and `Java 8`, as well as with `Spring Boot 2.7.1` and `Java 17`.

I have some incomplete mappings for an `@ElementCollection` which make manually inserted rows not to be fetched by the service, while rows inserted by the service itself are fetched as expected.

Here's a [project](https://github.com/flaviuratiu/element-collection-mapping-investigation) for reproducing the issue; instructions are provided in the repository readme file.

I'll also describe the problem in more generic terms below.

## Prerequisites:

- mysql column names in snake_case
- an entity with an embedded id having property names in camelCase, without a `@Column(name = "some_id")` annotation
- an `@ElementCollection` with `@JoinColumn` specifying `name`, but not `referencedColumnName`

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Have the service insert a row in the main entity table.
2. Execute an SQL insert in the db to insert a row in the collection table, linked to the main entity inserted at step 1.
3. Have the service read the main entity, with fetch type `EAGER` for the collection table.

## Expected result:

Step 3 should return the main entity with the manually inserted data from the collection table included.

## Actual result:

At step 3, the main entity is returned not including the element collection.
Very interesting though, if one was to have the row inserted in the collection table by the service,
the service would return at step 3 the main entity with the element collection included.

## The fix:

- the embedded id properties need to be annotated with `@Column(name = "some_id")`
- each `@JoinColumn` for the `@ElementCollection` should have both `name` and `referencedColumnName` specified.

## The question:

Could you please explain why the service is able to fetch the rows inserted by the service itself, but not the manually inserted rows, when using the incomplete column mappings? I would like to have a better understanding of how this mapping works.

Comment: You are using JPA - have you looked into how JPA caches your entity objects? Have you tried forcing a refresh on your entity instance (entityManager.refresh(entity)) to get it to reload the instance from the database?

Comment: I haven't thought of this, thanks. But the behaviour is the same even after a service restart, so I don't think it's cache related.

Comment: I didn't notice you had a 'fix'. When you insert through Spring, how many  SelectedRating instances can you insert and read back? Check the SQL that is used for the inserts and the reads, and verify how they are different. First guess is this is a Springism - they break with the JPA specification in many ways, one of which might be in how/what it forces Hibernate to use as the defaults for the joins and how they are done.